# Next.js Typescript environmental variables not working

Tags: typescript, next.js, environment-variables

I am using Next.js and EmailJS with Typescript. I am trying to use the environment variables without success. I created an env.local file and I wrote there some keys of EmailJS. When I tried to use them in certain component it says on the console: "Uncaught The user ID is required.". I tried to follow the documentation but it doesn't work. Also, I tried using the prefix NEXT_PUBLIC_ but it gives me the same error either way. I did a console log using both ways and always service, template or user are undefined. Below is the code:
env.local

> SERVICE_ID=service_123
>
> TEMPLATE_ID=template_123
>
> USER_ID=user_123

The jsx file:

```
export default const ContactUs = (props: {service: string; template: string; user: string}) => {
  
    const sendEmail = (e: any) => {
      e.preventDefault();
  
      emailjs.sendForm(props.service, props.template, e.target, props.user)
        .then((result) => {
            console.log(result.text);
        }, (error) => {
            console.log(error.text);
        });
        e.target.reset();
        setResult(true);      
    };
    return (<div>...</div>) 
};
export async function getStaticProps() {
    return {
        props: {
            service: process.env.SERVICE_ID,
            template: process.env.TEMPLATE_ID,
            user: process.env.USER_ID,
        }
    }
};
```

I hope there someone that can help me.

Comment: Is this related to: https://nextjs.org/docs/basic-features/environment-variables#exposing-environment-variables-to-the-browser

Comment: Hi @zecuria Yes, it is. The getStaticProps function I got it from that page.

Comment: No I mean't that if you read the link it says: In order to expose a variable to the browser you have to prefix the variable with `NEXT_PUBLIC_`.

Comment: I tried both ways. With the prefix NEXT_PUBLIC_ and without it and it gives me the same error

Comment: When you console.log the props inside the `sendEmail` are they all undefined?

Comment: Yes, they are. in both ways as well. I mean they are undefined with the prefix NEXT_PUBLIC_ or without it.

Comment: The env file name needs to be prefixed with a dot, e.g. `.env.local`.